# Swagger / OpenAPI spec featuring file upload rejected by Google Endpoints

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, swagger-2.0, openapi

My goal is to set up a simple API for uploading a file via Google Endpoints.

This is my simplified OpenAPI specification which is valid according to Swagger validation:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: "JSON Ingester"
  description: "Receive JSON files, transform and load them."
  version: "1.0.0"

host: "project-id.appspot.com"
schemes:
  - "https"

paths:
  /uploadFile:
    post:
      operationId: uploadFile
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - 
          in: formData
          name: upfile
          type: file
          description: file
      responses:
        200:
          description: "File uploaded."
        400:
          description: "Error during file upload."
```

I always end up with this obscure error message:

```
user@cloudshell:~/google-cloud-json-ingester (project-id)$ gcloud endpoints services deploy ./openapi.yaml
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config.
'location: "openapi.yaml: Operation \'post\' in path \'/uploadFile\'"
message: "Operation does not require an API key; callers may invoke the method without specifying an associated API-consuming project. To enable API key all the SecurityRequirement Objects (https://gi
thub.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object) inside security definition must reference at least one SecurityDefinition of type : \'apiKey\'."
 location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "http: repeated message field \'google.protobuf.Struct.fields\' referred to by message \'UploadFileRequest\' cannot be mapped as an HTTP parameter."
 location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "http: cyclic message field \'google.protobuf.Struct.FieldsEntry.value\' referred to by message \'UploadFileRequest\' in method \'method 1.project_id_appspot_com.UploadFile\' cannot
 be mapped as an HTTP parameter."
 location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "http: cyclic message field \'google.protobuf.ListValue.values\' referred to by message \'UploadFileRequest\' in method \'method 1.project_id_appspot_com.UploadFile\' cannot be mapp
ed as an HTTP parameter."
'
```

I've run out of ideas as to what might be the cause.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it requires at least some authentication: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method

I also think that Cloud Endpoints don't support *type: file*, so you have to use *type: string* and use equivalent to *curl -X POST -F "file_upload=@file.txt" http://myservice.com/endpoint* to upload.

Comment: I doubt authentication is the issue here b/c that same message will always be shown - even when going through for other paths - but then as a warning. Possible that Endpoints doesn't support "file" despite them explicitly advertising support of OpenAPI 2.0. Using type=string should be a viable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by copying and pasting my swagger file into https://editor.swagger.io/ to identify bugs and referencing https://swagger.io/specification/v2/ to fix the errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today and created a repro. I believe that your issue likely lies in the order of:

> in: formData
> name: upfile

If you are still seeing this issue, can you please try reversing the order:

> name: upfile
> in: formData